# Boxplot of feature X by a binary target group from a Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, boxplot

How do generate a boxplot for every numerical features by a binary target from a Spark dataframe please? 
 I am not able to extend this to consider the binary target stratification.

```
age_lst=final_sdf.select('Age','Recommended IND').collect()
counts=[row['Age'] for row in age_lst]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
ax[0].set_title('Age',fontsize=15)
ax[0].boxplot(counts,showmeans=True,notch=True)
ax[0].set_ylabel('years')
```

Comment: Managed to solve it with Pandas on Spark dataframe instead. Thanks.